# Nil vs List(Nil) in a for with recursion

Tags: list, scala, recursion

I'm learning Scala and have a quick question: Can someone please explain to me why the following two sets of code yield different results?

```
def grey0(n: Int): List[List[String]]={
  if (n==0) List(Nil)
  else for(i<-List("0","1"); j<-grey0(n-1)) yield i :: j 
 }
```

versus

```
def grey1(n: Int): List[List[String]]={
  if (n==0) Nil
  else for(i<-List("0","1"); j<-grey0(n-1)) yield i :: j 
 }
```

The first option yields the result I am looking for. What I don't understand is, why does the second option just return the empty list? I would have thought the other results would cons on to it and if anything, I would get some sort of flat list rather than a `List[List[String]]` (which is what I want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first version `grey0(0)` will return a 1-element list that contains the empty list. `grey0(1)` will, for each element in `grey0(0)` create two lists, so you get a total of two lists because `grey0(0)` contains one list. Likewise `grey0(2)` will contain 4 lists because for each of the two elements in `grey0(1)` it creates 2 lists.

In your second version `grey0(0)` will return the empty list. `grey0(1)` will create two lists for each element in `grey0(0)`. Since `grey0(0)` has 0 elements, that makes a total of `0*2=0` elements in the result.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you create a list containing an empty list. In the second example you create just an empty list. Both can have the same type, because any list can be empty.

`Nil` just means empty list and it is almost equal to `List()` (in your example types will be inferred so both are exactly the same). `List(Nil)` is then like `List(List())`.